# oralce apex text item save value in Session state in Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.1

I have Interactive Report and i have added text item as below

```
apex_item.text(
              p_idx           =>   3,
              p_value         =>   nvl(c.c003,'0'),
              p_item_id       =>   'f03_#ROWNUM#',
              p_item_label    =>   'f03_#ROWNUM#')
```

It shows a text item in IR which accept any text value to be saved in collections on submit, however while entering values in text item if i apply any filter on report and clear the filter it clear all the entered values in Text item.

Please see the [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tsOzQRnmVaAX-hxbJ7b0be6XWrGG2VM5/view?usp=sharing)o to describe the problem

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, but I'm not going to open any files from unknown sources.

---

If you want to use a report-like layout and be able to insert/update values, why wouldn't you rather use an **interactive grid**? It is updatable by default (if you set that property), and lets you do various filtering (similar to interactive report).

Because, although you *can* do that, why would you make your life more complicated than it should be? Use reports for reporting (viewing) purposes; use forms and interactive grid for updates, inserts and deletes. As simple as that.

Comment: I totally agree with you for Insert, Update and Delete Operation we must use IG or Forms , but in my case the Interactive Report has Multiple Tables displaying data along with apex_item.text . that's why i am using IR to display report correctly along with text item to accpept more information from user. Although i have handled to put value in collection and saving into actual tables. i am just facing this issue while filtering data as user want to put values in text for different filters but with filter text item get cleared.